# Granting write access to S3 in python cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cdk

I was able to follow this example<sup>1</sup> and let my ec2 instance read from S3.
In order to write to the same bucket I thought changing line 57<sup>2</sup> from `grant_read()` to `grant_read_write()`
should work.

```py
    ...
            # Userdata executes script from S3
            instance.user_data.add_execute_file_command(
                file_path=local_path
                )
            # asset.grant_read(instance.role)
            asset.grant_read_write(instance.role) 
    ...
```

Yet the documented<sup>3</sup> function cannot be accessed according to the error message.

```
>> 57: Pyright: Cannot access member "grant_read_write" for type "Asset"
```

What am I missing?

---

<sup>1</sup> https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/tree/master/python/ec2/instance

<sup>2</sup> https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/python/ec2/instance/app.py#L57

<sup>3</sup> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/permissions.html#permissions_grants

Answer (score 1):

This is the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3_assets/Asset.html) for Asset:

> An asset represents a local file or directory, which is automatically
> uploaded to S3 and then can be referenced within a CDK application.

The method grant_read_write isn't provided, as it is pointless. The documentation you've linked doesn't apply here.

Answer (score 0):

an asset is just a Zip file that will be uploded to the bootstraped CDK s3 bucket, then referenced by Cloudformation when deploying.

if you have an script you want ot put into an s3 bucket, you dont want to use any form of asset cause that is a zip file. You would be better suited using a boto3 command to upload it once the bucket already exists, or making it part of a codePipeline to create the bucket with CDK then the next step in the pipeline uploads it.

the grant_read_write is for `aws_cdk.aws_s3.Bucket` constructs in this case.